# How do I block a user-agent from Apache

Tags: googlebot, apache2, apache-log-files, web-crawlers

How do I realize a UA string block by regular expression in the config files of my Apache webserver?

For example: if I would like to block out all bots from Apache on my debian server, that have the regular expression `/\b\w+[Bb]ot\b/` or `/Spider/` in their user-agent.

Those bots should not be able to see any page on my server and they should not appear neither in the accesslogs nor in the errorlogs.

`http://global-security.blogspot.de/2009/06/how-to-block-robots-before-they-hit.html` supposes to uses `mod_security` for that, but isn't there a simple directive for *http.conf*?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just have them not crawl your site using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)? (seems more efficient then doing an Apache regex for every request)

Comment: I have many websites on the server, so I would have to add a robots.txt to each folders at once and only if there is none yet. the simplest solution would be such a directive in the main config. And I want to unclutter the accesslogs and errorlogs too

Comment: I see. I'm not sure specific regexes are going to catch them all, particularly those with differing or missing UA's. See this for more:  [Crawler Identification and Examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Crawler_identification)

Comment: I know I can't get them all, but I still would like to add this easy solution to reduce some traffic and logging. I dot't need a complete solution, just an easy question: *What line would I have to add in the apache-config?* I can't find it ;)

Comment: I'll take a look at the regex for what you have. Here's list of UA's for spiders, robots, and crawlers though: [List of User-Agents](http://www.user-agents.org/) The regex will be very incomplete indeed.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking about a better RegEx, I ask how to implement a custom RegEx in the apache config

Comment: I continued searching and [found this on hostgator.com](http://forums.hostgator.com/showpost.php?p=162491&postcount=6) maybe that helps

Answer (score 1):

I enabled rewrite engine in Apache:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and added this block to my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sosospider [NC,OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BaiduSpider [NC]
                # Allow access to robots.txt and forbidden message
                # at least 403 or else it will loop
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/403\.shtml$
                RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
       </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

and restarted Apache:

```
apache2ctl graceful
```

now these calls from those spiders all cause **403 Errors**:

```
grep -E 'spider|bot' /var/log/apache2/*.log
```